# Android instant app permission request dialog not shown

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-instant-apps

I'm currently working on instant apps for Android and I want to use the Camera.
I'm requesting the camera permission in a Fragment, but the Permission request dialog doesn't appear.

This is how I request the permission in the Fragment:

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
```

Now I expect, that the Permission request dialog is displayed, as it is for the Application itself (com.android.application). Unfortunately it doesn't appear for the instant app (com.android.instantapp).

Additionally I figured out that the

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(final int requestCode, @NonNull final String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{...}
```

is called but with `grantResults[0] = -1`, which means `PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED`.

As per the [Instant Apps FAQ](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html) it should be the same as for the application:

> **How do permissions work in Google Play Instant?**
>
> Google Play Instant uses the [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) model that was introduced in Android 6.0 (API level 23).

The same problem occurs, if I add a permission request for the Instant App Demo project from Google ([android-topeka](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-topeka)).

Comment: use this tutorial for permission use in fragments: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/11/android-working-marshmallow-m-runtime-permissions/

Comment: Thx, but it's working for the Application itself (com.android.application), but not for the Instant App (com.android.instantapp).

Comment: Is there some chance that you hit "don't ask again" ? This will skip the dialog and go straight to -1. I don't have any issues requesting CAMERA permission at all, pre-O and O+.

Comment: Try building a bare-bones instant app with just that one camera request permission to see if it works on your device, but I'd say you've probably got something amiss in your main project.

Comment: If the sample project also doesn't work, then maybe something is wrong with your device, try another device/emulator? Or submit a bugreport to https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=316045&template=1018787

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this only happens on my HUAWEI Mate 10 Pro. I've tested on several devices and everything works, as expected.

Currently I haven't an idea why the permission request doesn't work on the HUAWEI device, but I think it's related to the EMUI-System.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're missing to add camera permission to manifest.
Add camera permission to your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

I hope this'll fix your problem.

Comment: Thx, I've added the camera permission to the manifest, but it behaves as if this is not configured. Also the APK analyzer shows the correct entry in the Manifest.